# My AHK script keeps saying invalid hotkey

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I'm trying to set up my function keys to adjust volume (like it did on my laptop), but I can't seem to get it to work. It just keeps saying invalid hotkey on line F5. Here's my code:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

BackspaceF9::
Volume_Down

BackspaceF10::
Volume_Up

BackspaceF11::
Volume_Mute
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you intend to combine `Backspace` and some of the F-keys? For example `Backspace` + `F10` to raise the volume?

Answer (score 0):

Use an Ampersand if you intend to combine Backspace and the Function keys.  See AutoHotkey help topic for Hotkeys.